# Colons in field names messes up d3 code

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have data for which the column names in each fields include colons (e.g. "data:age"). This messes up my d3 functions, like the selection data methods. For example, this wouldn't work:

```
.data(data, function(d) { return d.data:age; })
```

Does anyone have suggestions on the best way to get around this? Escaping with \ doesn't do the trick. I cannot change the column names from the data feed.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried `d['data:age']`?

Comment: I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can also access attributes through `[]`, i.e. `d['data:age']`.